# mysqli cannot create a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a trouble with my mysql. It connects to database but it doesn't make a table. Here is an example of my code:

```
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user.name', 'user.pass', 'db');

  if ($db === FALSE) {
     echo "ERRROR";
  }   

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db (
      ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      NAME VARCHAR(20) NULL
  )";

  $db->query($sql);

  if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
     echo "TABLE CREATED SUCCESSFULLY";
  } else {
    echo "TABLE CREATED UNSUCCESSFULLY";
  }
```

I appreciate every answer, thank you for help!

Comment: Can you try adding this to the script? It should give us a error message:  echo("TABLE CREATED UNSUCCESSFULLY: " . mysqli_error($sql));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL only allows auto-increment columns if they are defined as a key. Given that the column is labelled ID, which means you probably want it as a primary key, try this:

```
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db (
      ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      NAME VARCHAR(20) NULL
  )";
```

Comment: yeah It works!!! thank you so much!

Comment: Make sure to mark this answer as accepted ig it solves your problem. Just hit the green check-mark next to this answer.

Comment: sure I have to wait 2 minutes :D

Answer (score 1):

Because there is error in MySQL query

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db (
      ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      NAME VARCHAR(20) NULL;
```

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

fix :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db (
      ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      NAME VARCHAR(20) NULL,
      key idx_ID(ID)
     );
```

PRIMARY KEY is not compulsory, normal key can work too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this.

```
 $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user.name', 'user.pass', 'db');

  if ($db === FALSE) {
     echo "ERRROR";
  }   

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db (
      ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      NAME VARCHAR(20) NULL
  )";

  $db->query($sql);

  if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
     echo "TABLE CREATED SUCCESSFULLY";
  } else {
    echo "TABLE CREATED UNSUCCESSFULLY";
  }
```